# Condition (C) of Palais-Smale

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

In Klingenberg's Notes, he makes the following definition:

> $\Lambda M$ will be said to satisfy the condition (C) of Palais-Smale if:
>
> Given a sequence $\{c_m\}$ on $\Lambda M$ satisfying:
>
> (i) The sequence $\{E(c_m)\}$ is bounded
>
> (ii) The sequence $\{||\text{grad} ~E(c_m)||_1\}$ tends to zero
>
> Then $\{c_m\}$ has limit points and any limit point is a critical point of $E$

He then proceeds to prove $\Lambda M$ satisfies the condition (C). (OBS: $\Lambda M$ is the free loop space of a compact riemannian manifold)

But  I think something is wrong... is it really *limit point* that he wants?

I think he means that $c_m$ has some convergent subsequence... and every subsequence limit is a critical point. Is that it?

Comment: The term limit point has different definitions depending on the author. For instance, I probably think what you call an adherent point is a limit point, and I've never heard the term adherent point in my life until now.

Comment: Even so, it doesn't make sense to be adherent point... I am confused.

Comment: I don't know the context, but I imagine it means "There are points $x$ such that any neighborhood of $x$ contains $c_m$ for infinitely many $m$. Any such point is a critical point." This is how I would interpret it in a vacuum. E: This agrees with your edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He means that $c_m$ has some convergent subsequence.